# Oracle 12.2c JDBC Protocol violation error

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle12c

I am trying to read data from a large piece of SQL from an Oracle 12.2c database using the v8 jdbc drivers (I have tried the v7 driver too)

Every time it fails with the following error

```
2018/02/22 10:12:53: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [ 6, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, 21, 7, ]
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:645)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1023)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3353)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:736)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:692)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:406)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at com.connexica.cxair.indexes.crawler.DatabaseCrawlerAgent.process(DatabaseCrawlerAgent.java:669)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at com.connexica.cxair.indexes.crawler.BaseCustomCrawlerAgent.restart(BaseCustomCrawlerAgent.java:249)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at com.connexica.cxair.indexes.crawler.BaseCustomCrawlerAgent.start(BaseCustomCrawlerAgent.java:183)
2018/02/22 10:12:53:    at com.connexica.cxair.indexes.crawler.ThreadCrawlerAgent.run(ThreadCrawlerAgent.java:69)
```

I have now tried this using the SQL/a view based off the SQL and a table created from the SQL. Both the view and SQL fail on exactly the same row every time. The table works.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: it may helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372626/sqlexception-protocol-violation-in-oracle

Comment: How are you connecting? What does the jdbc url look like?

Comment: There is no such thing as a v8 or v7 driver. Those drivers have a version number that looks a lot like an Oracle database version number, like 12.2.0.1 or 12.1.0.2. The 7 or 8 in the jar name indicates the target Java version.

Comment: There's all sort of things this could be. Try reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29372626/146325) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35343994/146325) to get some insights.